# Select mysql join on crystal report

Tags: mysql, vb.net, join

Good day,

I have two tables which i want to report on crystal report.
im joining two tables to meet the desired output.
my code works fine in mysql but when i run my code on crystal report, it returns multiple rows.
Below are my code.

```vb
Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
Dim adp As New MySqlDataAdapter
Dim dt As New DataSet
Dim sql As String

Dim l = Leaves


sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM leave_data AS ld INNER JOIN leavess AS l ON ld.leave_id = l.leave_id WHERE l.applicableYear = '2019' AND ld.dateOfLeave BETWEEN '2019-09-01' AND '2019-09-15' GROUP BY ld.leaveData_id"

cn.Open()

cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, cn)

adp.SelectCommand = cmd
adp.Fill(dt, "leave_data")
adp.Fill(dt, "leavess")


Dim report As New crPrintSearch
report.SetDataSource(dt)


printSearch.rvPrintSearch.ReportSource = report
printSearch.rvPrintSearch.Refresh()



cmd.Dispose()
adp.Dispose()
dt.Dispose()
cn.Close()

printSearch.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: It is hard to tell, where your Problem is, because it is unknown what the result of the Select is, nor how the original data was. My first guess is that your select wouldn't work on mysql wprkbench either correctly. Try to buid a meanigful representation of your problom on dbfiddle or sqlfiddle. and read this please https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: it works perfectly on my sql editor. But its different on crystal report. Thanks tho.

Comment: ok ´, if that is the case, then change crPrintSearch and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your sql query is wrong. Not that it does not work in mySql, it just should be done different when working with a report.

You have a dataset with 2 tables (leave_data and leavess).
You are using the same query to populate both tables. This will result in 2 tables with the same data.

I am assuming that the in the report you have these 2 tables.

Your query gets data from 2 tables and the result of it is a single table, not 2.

Try changing you sql to have 2 selects:

SELECT DISTINCT leave_data.* FROM leave_data INNER JOIN leavess ...

SELECT DISTINCT leavess.* FROM leave_data INNER JOIN leavess ...

This would result in a dataset with 2 tables.

If you are using a single table inside the report, then keep your query, but do not do this:

adp.Fill(dt, "leave_data")

adp.Fill(dt, "leavess")

just do this:

adp.Fill(dt)

A second table in not required.

Selecting only the fields required in the report is a good practice, so you might want to reconsider your "Select distinct *", and put the names of the fields. Also, as it is, your query results in a table with the field leave_id duplicated.

Comment: It fucking works man. I just added a second sql command to fill my data adapter on a single data set.  Thank you, i really appreciate your effort sir. The world needs more people like you.